# std::thread in C++ vs. goroutine in go language?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, go, cloud

The nature of gorouting in go language is an automatic fiber/coroutine.

The nature of std::thread in C++ is a wrapper of native threads.

I think std::thread should be an abstraction of parallel works, not just for native threads. In cloud computing era, it's very important.

Is there any way to use std::thread like the following:

```
std::thread<GoroutingStyle>    t1;
std::thread<NativeThreadStyle> t2;
```

Or if not, does the C++ standard consider to add some features/libraries to support goroutine?

Comment: You can find coroutine libraries freely available for C/C++ if you search for them. The language doesn't need to provide explicit support. Wrapping them from there should not be difficult.

Comment: @mah The language also doesn't need explicit support for containers, so we should go ahead and remove `std::vector` and co I assume? That said as usual [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/coroutine/doc/html/index.html) helps the anemic C++ standard library out.

Comment: @Voo I never suggested that such support could not or even should not be added (I have no opinion either way), I merely mentioned that existing support is not required in order to make use of a wrapped co-routine model. You seem to have read more into things than was provided.

Comment: @mah In that case I apologize. I've got a bit of a thin hide on this point, because so many people seem to defend C++'s by far largest problem (deficient standard library) by saying "just use one of those libraries" ignoring the portability and quality problems that arise with such a solution.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a `<GoroutineStyle>` rather than a `<CoroutineStyle>`?

Comment: I don’t get why you want to use std::thread for coroutining. A std::thread is an abstraction for *threads*. Why would it be made more general then what it abstracts?

Comment: @Kissaki, I think std::thread should be an abstraction of parallel works, not just for native threads. In cloud computing era, it's very important.

Comment: @Voo: Don't aim that criticism at Boost. Its explicit goal is standardizing new libraries for inclusion into a future Standard.

Comment: @MSalters I'm very grateful for boost and know of its goals. I'm more frustrated with the slow process of actually getting its libraries into the standard. E.g.: Great we finally have low level concurrent abstractions in the standard library, will we get concurrent data structures this decade or the next?

Answer (score 1):

> Or if not, does the C++ standard consider to add some features/libraries to support goroutine?

what you are requesting is something like a fiber library - the forthcoming library boost.fiber contains cooperatively scheduled fibers, mutexes/condition-vairables/barriers/... - the interface is similar to boost.thread.